# CasperJS (phantom 1.9.7), connection https is not possible since yesterday

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Since yesterday, I have a problem with CasperJS and one site. It's actually impossible to connect server since yesterday. BUT, my script on windows works fine. I have this error on my production server:

```
2015-04-01T09:46:02 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
2015-04-01T09:46:02 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 2 ( "Connection closed" ) URL: "https://www.mysite.fr/"
[error] [phantom] Resource https://www.mysite.fr/ failed to load (null)
2015-04-01T09:46:02 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100
```

I use:

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --web-security=no --debug=yes script.js
```

So, in windows (1.9.7) function perfect but since yesterday, script on my linux doesn't work as seen by the output above.

Comment: It would be nice to know what changed on the target site.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i use casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --ssl-protocol=tlsv1
Nothing change on server (our providers say that)

Comment: Do you use a Debian-based linux? If yes then check if some dependencies of PhantomJS were updated. Dependencies can be shown like this: `ldd /usr/local/bin/phantomjs` and update log is under `/var/log` e.g.: `grep upgrade /var/log/dpkg.log.1` or `grep upgrade /var/log/dpkg.log`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Nothing change on target site. We have 2 site, one for preprod et one in prod. 

In préprod (site): no https : with my linux server, it's functionnaly
and with windows, functionnaly too

In prod (site) : with https : 
with my linux server, is not functionnaly since yesterday 
but with my windows, functionnaly

Our provider say : nothing change in target site, and nothing change on hosting

Comment: @ArtjomB. We don't have update since 26 march on our linux system. 30 mars, script functionnaly very well

Comment: Then obviously someone is lying. A computer doesn't simply decide to do things differently from one day to the other without some other change except if it's broken. Is your testing/scraping machine broken?

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=any script.js
```

Alternative method: Update to PhantomJS 1.9.8 or higher

you can do it by using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo npm install -g casperjs
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the only method that worked for me:

```
casperjs test.js --config=<(echo '{"sslProtocol": "any"}') --ignore-ssl-errors=true
```

PhantomJS 2.1, CasperJS 1.1